# How to send/publish Selenium Test Reports through email notification in Jenkins?

Tags: selenium, junit, jenkins, report, email-notifications

I can publish and look at Selenium (junit) Test Reports in Jenkins. I can also send email notification to developers. I want to include Selenium Test Report with email notification, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the plugin `Editable Email Notification` for Jenkins.

In the Default Content text field (which you will be able to find when trying to configure a Jenkins job under Editable Email Notification) put 
`${JELLY_SCRIPT,template="text"}`
there is also an HTML template which you can use.